# Ionic live-reload executes twice on save

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-cli

Every time I make a change to my code, live-reload executes twice. The first reload is quick (< 1 second), then there is a pause, then another reload fires and takes substantially longer (2 - 3 seconds).

When I create a fresh Ionic starter app, I don't get this problem. I have tried different IDEs and get the same result.

My ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/alexandrsteinberg/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (/Users/alexandrsteinberg/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Comment: What is the command you are using to run live-reload? What is the output you are getting? What is different in your project than in a "fresh Ionic starter app"?

Comment: I'm using `ionic serve` and the output is pretty standard. There is _a lot_ different in my project but I wouldn't know where to start to find the source of this problem.

Comment: If you are using [`ionic serve`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve), this question has nothing to do with Cordova as that command runs a local webserver.